# I'm trying to draw list items in the Inspector but it's not working how can I replace the element0,element1....with my own string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(PickupObjects))]
public class PickupObjectsEditor : Editor
{
    private static List<GameObject> pickeditems = new List<GameObject>();
    private static bool picked = false;
    private SerializedProperty _serializedpickeditems;

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Generate as Pickup Item", false, 30)]
    public static void GeneratePickupItems()
    {
        if (Selection.gameObjects.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Selection.gameObjects.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Selection.gameObjects[i].GetComponent<TestScript>() == null)
                {
                    Selection.gameObjects[i].AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
                    Selection.gameObjects[i].AddComponent<TestScript>();
                }

                Selection.gameObjects[i].layer = 9;
                Selection.gameObjects[i].tag = "Pickup Item";

                pickeditems.Add(Selection.gameObjects[i]);
            }

            picked = true;
        }
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        PickupObjects myTarget = (PickupObjects)target;

        DrawDefaultInspector();

        if (picked == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pickeditems.Count; i++)
            {
                myTarget.pickUpObjects.Add(pickeditems[i]);

                var item = _serializedpickeditems.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                var serializedItem = new SerializedObject(item.objectReferenceValue);
                serializedItem.Update();

                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item, new GUIContent("Picked Item " + i + " " + item.name));
                serializedItem.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            }

            pickeditems.Clear();
            picked = false;
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _serializedpickeditems = serializedObject.FindProperty("pickUpObjects");
    }
}
```

And the mono script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickupObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> pickUpObjects = new List<GameObject>();
}
```

I tried to use serialize and PropertyField but still it's showing the List with Element0,Element1,Element2.... And I want it to be :

```
Picked Item Box
Picked Item Can
Picked Item Cube
Picked Item Dock_Pod
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item, new GUIContent("Picked Item " + i + " " + item.name));
```

sits within a code block that is only executed **once**.

What you see currently is actually **only** the list drawn by

```
DrawDefaultInspector();
```

since the rest is disappeared after 1 frame/draw call.

---

You would rather want to separate the pick "method" from the drawing like e.g.

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    serializedObject.Update();

    if (picked)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < pickeditems.Count; i++)
        {
            // NOTE: Never mix serializedProperties and direct access/modifications on the target!
            // This messes up the marking dirty and saving these changes!
            // Rather always go through the SerializedProperties so the editor handles everything automatically
            _serializedpickeditems.arraySize++;
            _serializedpickeditems.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue = pickeditems[i];
        }

        picked = false;
        pickeditems.Clear();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < _serializedpickeditems.arraySize; i++)
    {
        var item = _serializedpickeditems.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

        // little bonus from me: Color the field if the value is null ;)
        var color = GUI.color;
        if(!item.objectReferenceValue) GUI.color = Color.red;
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item, new GUIContent("Picked Item " + i + " " + (item.objectReferenceValue ? item.objectReferenceValue.name : "null")));
        }
        GUI.color = color;

        // The only case you would need to go deeper here and use 
        // your new SerializedObject would be if you actually make changes
        // to these objects/components like e.g. directly allow to edit their name
    }

    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

---

Note you should also clear the `pickeditems` list before adding new items:

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Generate as Pickup Item", false, 30)]
public static void GeneratePickupItems()
{
    if (Selection.gameObjects.Length > 0)
    {
        pickeditems.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < Selection.gameObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Selection.gameObjects[i].GetComponent<Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractablePickupScript>() == null)
            {
                Selection.gameObjects[i].AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
                Selection.gameObjects[i].AddComponent<Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractablePickupScript>();
            }

            Selection.gameObjects[i].layer = 9;
            Selection.gameObjects[i].tag = "Pickup Item";

            pickeditems.Add(Selection.gameObjects[i]);
        }

        picked = true;
    }
}
```

---

[image]

---

In general I always recommend to use a [`ReorderableList`](https://va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist)!

It's a bit tricky at first to get into it but as soon as you have set it up it is an amazing tool. even if you don't make it actually reorderable it is still a huge advantage to be e.g. able to dynamically remove an item from the middle ;)

Comment: There is a problem. picked flag is true all the time and _serializedpickeditems is null all the time.  Maybe I put the flag picked = true in the wrong place ?

Comment: Don't know it works for me .. a you sure you didn't miss something like resetting the `pick` flag?

Comment: It's working. For some reason the OnEnable at my side removed. My mistake.