# Why the when adding new item to the list it's replacing it with the item at index 0 instead adding new item at the end?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this case the list is at size 17 (index 0 to 16)
And each time when adding new item it's replacing the new item with the one at index 0 instead adding new item to and make the list size bigger.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(PickupObjects))]
public class PickupObjectsEditor : Editor
{
    private static List<GameObject> pickeditems = new List<GameObject>();
    private static bool picked = false;
    private SerializedProperty _serializedpickeditems;
    private Vector2 scrollPos;

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Generate as Pickup Item", false, 30)]
    public static void GeneratePickupItems()
    {
        if (Selection.gameObjects.Length > 0)
        {
            pickeditems.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < Selection.gameObjects.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Selection.gameObjects[i].GetComponent<Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractablePickupScript>() == null)
                {
                    Selection.gameObjects[i].AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
                    Selection.gameObjects[i].AddComponent<Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractablePickupScript>();
                }

                Selection.gameObjects[i].layer = 9;
                Selection.gameObjects[i].tag = "Pickup Item";

                pickeditems.Add(Selection.gameObjects[i]);
            }

            picked = true;
        }
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        if (picked)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < pickeditems.Count; i++)
            {
                // NOTE: Never mix serializedProperties and direct access/modifications on the target!
                // This messes up the marking dirty and saving these changes!
                // Rather always go through the SerializedProperties so the editor handles everything automatically
                _serializedpickeditems.arraySize++;
                _serializedpickeditems.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue = pickeditems[i];
            }

            picked = false;
            pickeditems.Clear();
        }

        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));

        var color = GUI.color;
        for (var i = 0; i < _serializedpickeditems.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var item = _serializedpickeditems.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            // little bonus from me: Color the field if the value is null ;)

            if (!item.objectReferenceValue) GUI.color = Color.red;
            {
                if (item.objectReferenceValue != null)
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item, new GUIContent("Picked Item " + i + " ")); //+ (item.objectReferenceValue ? item.objectReferenceValue.name : "null")));
                }
            }
            GUI.color = color;

            // The only case you would need to go deeper here and use 
            // your new SerializedObject would be if you actually make changes
            // to these objects/components like e.g. directly allow to edit their name
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _serializedpickeditems = serializedObject.FindProperty("pickUpObjects");
    }
}
```

And the mono script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickupObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> pickUpObjects = new List<GameObject>();
}
```

Comment: In the first script, where is Selection coming from?

Comment: @BugFinder The Selection is part of the UnityEditor class it's when you select objects in the Hierarchy.

Comment: does it vary with where things are relative in the hierarchy? as because each selected item is assumed to be the same as before say 0-5, and 6 must be the new one, but it could be due to position etc it comes in at the top.. therefore its getting very confused

Comment: The generic list does not behave that way... Period.  So the error must be in your logic. You are clearing the list everytime... So the order depends on the input not the list itself... in other words you are recreating the list everytime.

Comment: So the order really depends on Selection.gameObjects which is being fed into the list everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this was a mistake of mine in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771927/7111561)!

It should actually be

```
_serializedpickeditems.arraySize++;
_serializedpickeditems.GetArrayElementAtIndex(_serializedpickeditems.arraySize - 1).objectReferenceValue = pickeditems[i];
```

in order to add objects in the end of the list!